# how to transform mongoose.find() documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my node.js mongoose query. The find query selects three properties : _id, userName and isManager.
I need to change the name of "_id" key to "empId" before sending the response. How do I do it?

```
exports.getEmployeeUserNames = (req, res, next) => {
  Employee.find({ 'userName': { '$nin': [null, ""] }})
    .sort('fName')
    .select('_id userName isManager')
    .then( documents => {

      // NEED TO CHANGE THE _id to empId
      // the res documents shd have structure { empId:..., userName:..., isManager:...}

      res.status(200).json(documents);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Employee data!"
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this through mongo or on nodejs-side? Both is possible.

Comment: Which is better? Request you to explain both options.

Comment: Well, if it's a huge list of documents that you need to map/loop through, you'll get slightly better performance if you let mongo do it. You're essentially blocking the event-loop during the mapping process.

Comment: In favor of @eol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you would have to assign the `_id` value to `empId` then delete the `_id`

try

```
exports.getEmployeeUserNames = (req, res, next) => {
  Employee.find({ 'userName': { '$nin': [null, ""] } })
    .sort('fName')
    .select('_id userName isManager')
    .then(documents => {

      // NEED TO CHANGE THE _id to empId
      // the res documents shd have structure { empId:..., userName:..., isManager:...}

      const empDocuments = documents.map(doc => {
        Object.defineProperty(doc, 'empId', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(doc, '_id'));
        delete doc._id
        return doc
      })

      res.status(200).json({empDocuments});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Employee data!"
      });
    });
}
```

another solution (Nikita Mazur's comment)

```
exports.getEmployeeUserNames = (req, res, next) => {
  Employee.find({ 'userName': { '$nin': [null, ""] } })
    .sort('fName')
    .select('_id userName isManager')
    .then(documents => {

      // NEED TO CHANGE THE _id to empId
      // the res documents shd have structure { empId:..., userName:..., isManager:...}

      const empDocuments = documents.map(doc => ({ empId: doc._id, userName: doc.userName, isManager: doc.isManager }))

      res.status(200).json(empDocuments);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Employee data!"
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: this will not work) you are not returning anything from map func, better change to
`documents.map(doc => ({ empId: doc._id, userName: doc.userName, isManager: doc.isManager }))`

Comment: Why not just do `doc._empId = doc._id` instead if using defineProperty? 

Comment: @NikitaMazur you're right, forgot the return statement

Comment: @Ajay map returns new array it doesn't change the initial array

Comment: @NikitaMazur I am talking about whats happening inside the `map`. Instead of doing `Object.defineProperty`, why not just create a new property directly. We are modifying the original array anyways because of the `delete doc.id` statement.

Comment: @Ajay well, no reason, you can do `doc._empId = doc._id` I just did the first solution that came to my mind

Comment: @MohamedOraby, now it looks better)

Comment: @NikitaMazur I also added your answer

Comment: The first solution gives an Internal Server error 500
The second solution returns the original array.

Comment: do I need to assign this to a new const?  documents.map(doc => ({ empId: doc._id, userName: doc.userName, isManager: doc.isManager }))

Comment: Try the second solution now

Comment: @hemant, yeah, have to assign to new const)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work because most likely mongoose doesn't allow to mess with its documents)

Comment: Cool the second solution worked.. Thanks people. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code is commented so as to give a better understanding on what's happening in each statement.

```js
// 
// Approach 1: Modifying the actual object
//

const arr = [{
    _id: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 3
  },
]

const result = arr.map(x => {
  // Create a new property in the same object
  // and assign the desired value to it
  x.empId = x._id;

  // Delete the _id property from the object
  delete x._id;

  // Return the object;
  return x;
});

console.log('Approach 1: Result:', result) // Desired Result
console.log('Approach 1: Arr:', arr) // Original Array Changed

// 
// Approach 2: Creating a new object
// 

const arr2 = [{
    _id: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 3
  },
]

const result2 = arr2.map(x => {
  // Create a new object
  const newObject = {
    // Spread everything from the original object
    // See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/
    ...x,

    // Create a new property in the new object
    empId: x._id
  };

  // Delete _id property from the new object
  delete newObject._id;

  // Return the new object instead of the original one
  return newObject;
});

console.log('Approach 2: Result:', result2) // Desired Result
console.log('Approach 2: Arr2:', arr2) // Original Array unchanged
```